# Exporting from Corel: file format field list is empty

Tags: export, file-format, corel-draw

I have a problem when exporting any file from Corel. When I try to choose a format, the list appears blank.

Is there anything I can do?

[image]

Comment: Your question is very unclear, please explain better. Which Corel version? Which OS? What is the filetype of your file, with which filetype do you want to export?

Comment: @Kurt Based on the photo you can tell 2 of 3 of those questions

Answer (score 1):

A) I think that is an instalation problem.

Re install your program. The wizard will ask you if you want to repair or remove the instalation. Choose repair.

B) There is a chance you did not install any export format libraries.

Look for them in:

Tools > Options

and in the left column look for Global > Filters.

There you can choose wich export/import formats you need.